# Obtener el id de una columna de base de datos

Tags: mysql, laravel

Estoy intentando buscar el id de una venta con el fin de actualizar la tabla de detalleVenta. Esta cuando ya se ha cobrado dicha venta.

Tengo una función de esta manera, en la tabla venta busca y actualiza el id de la venta pero en su detalle no lo genera. Como puedo saber cual es el id de la venta para actualizar la tabla de detalle

```
public function cobrar(Request $request, $id)
{
    $buscarPago = VentaUtp::findOrFail($id);
    $buscarPago->cantidadPagada="300";
    $buscarPago->update();


    $actualizarDetalle = DB::table('alumnopagosdet')
    ->select('idAlumnoCxC')
    ->where('idAlumnoCxC', '=', $id)
    ->get();


    $mytime = Carbon::now('America/Mexico_City');
    $venta->fecha_hora=$mytime->toDateTimeString();

    $actualizarPago = DetalleVentaUtp::findOrFail($detalle);
    $actualizarPago->fecha= $venta;
    $actualizarPago->caja=$request->get('caja');
    $actualizarPago->reciboCaja=$request->get('reciboCaja');
    $actualizarPago->anio=$request->get('anio');
    $actualizarPago->mes=$request->get('mes');
    $actualizarPago->cantidad=$buscarPago->cantidadPagada;
    $actualizarPago->update();

    return Redirect::to('utp/venta');


}
```

Answer (score 0):

la forma que esta recibiendo los datos esta mal no se utiliza el metodo get 
aqui le dejor una correcion de codigo 
no se que esta haciendo esta consulta

```
$actualizarDetalle = DB::table('alumnopagosdet')
    ->select('idAlumnoCxC')
    ->where('idAlumnoCxC', '=', $id)
    ->get();
```

aqui esta el ejemplo si lo va a enviar por metodo post , las validaciones depende los datos que se envie o el tipo de caracteres

```
 <?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Validator;
use Response;
use App\BarriosModel;
use App\AsistenciaModel;
use View;

class AsistenciaController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct(){
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }
    /**
    * @var array
    */
    protected $rules =
    [
                'caja' => 'required|min:2|max:255|regex:/^([0-9a-zA-ZñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ_-])+((\s*)+([0-9a-zA-ZñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ_-]*)*)+$/',
                'reciboCaja' => 'required|min:1|max:99999999',
                'anio' => 'required|min:2|max:255|regex:/^([0-9a-zA-ZñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ_-])+((\s*)+([0-9a-zA-ZñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ_-]*)*)+$/',
                'mes' => 'required|min:2|max:255|regex:/^([0-9a-zA-ZñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ_-])+((\s*)+([0-9a-zA-ZñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ_-]*)*)+$/',
    ];
public function update(Request $request, $id){
        $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $this->rules);
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return Response::json(array('errors' => $validator->getMessageBag()->toArray()));
        } else {

                $buscarPago = VentaUtp::findOrFail($id);
                $buscarPago->cantidadPagada="300";
                $buscarPago->update();

                $actualizarPago = DetalleVentaUtp::findOrFail($id);

                $actualizarPago->fecha= $venta;
                $actualizarPago->caja=$request->caja;
                $actualizarPago->reciboCaja=$request->reciboCaja;
                $actualizarPago->anio=$request->anio;
                $actualizarPago->mes=$request->mes;
                $actualizarPago->cantidad=$buscarPago->cantidadPagada;


                $actualizarPago->save();
                return response()->json($actualizarPago);
        }
    }

?>
```